# openness of geometric shape in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, trigonometry

Let $a$ denote the function that takes a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and returns the positive angle between this vector and the $x$ axis. (i.e., $a(0,1) = \pi/2$, $a(0,0) = 0$....).

My question is, how can I show that the set $\{ x \ | \ a(x) \in (b,c), b,c \in [0,2\pi]\}$ is open? It is the preimage of the open set $(b,c)$ under $a$, but is $a$ a continuous function?

Comment: You mean $a(0,1)=\pi/2$? It's worth thinking about why it is hard to define $a(0,0)$ in a continuous way.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition (where $a(0,0)$ is taken to be zero), this is not true. For instance, the set of angles between $-\pi/4$ and $\pi/4$ has the point $(0,0)$ in it. Then it's not hard to see that this set is not open, because we can find a sequence in its complement converging to zero.

There is a more standard way to define the angle function. It so happens that there's no way to define the angle function continuously on a set including zero. The most common way to make it a continuous function is to delete a half-line, for example to delete the non-negative real numbers, and define the angle function there.

For the same reason as above, any definition of the angle of zero will have problems with your openness condition.

Comment: All right. Assume we take this as our new definition of $a$. How can I then show continuity of the set $\{ a(x) \in (b,c)\}$? I am more interested in how one shows openness of sets involving functions that aren't neatly defined everywhere and continuous, like $a$ here.

Comment: The definition of a continuous function is that the inverse of an open set is open. Do you mean how can you show that this definition of $a$ is continuous? You could start by taking a sequence converging in the domain, and looking at what happens to the argument. Around the point of convergence, take a neighborhood small enough so that you don't bump into the half-line you deleted.